# Phishing Warning in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, https, phishing

I have a website that generates an email when a user registers.  The email has a link (a http get) to an API that confirms the user's email address.   The API returns a "true" value. Note, the API is an Azure website.

The get link in the email is of the form:

```
https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/AddressVerification/%7Bid%7D?emalAddress=user@xxx.com
```

This link works in Edge and Safari browsers and the user profile is correctly updated.  HOWEVER, in Chrome it triggers a phishing warning.
It should be noted that non-get calls to the website from Chrome do not get the phishing warning.

Is there a way to prevent the phishing warning in Chrome when executing a get?

In Chrome, I tried the link:

```
https://website_URL/api/AddressVerification/%7Bid%7D?emalAddress=user@xxx.com
```

I expect a return of "true" but got a phishing warning.

Comment: Side note: when you do very questionable things (like update DB on get, especially user info) there is no need to tell everyone about that - this particular detail has no relation to the question you are asking and can be safely omitted.

Comment: OK.  The question was modified.

Comment: Just guessing, but Chrome might consider the threat level lower if the call was to a domain registered by you ( api.mycompany.com ) instead of a free subdomain provided by Microsoft.

Comment: I submitted the page to Chrome for review and the warning was removed.